# ¿como insertar en sqlite 3 desde java?

Tags: java, sqlite

hice un codigo java con jframes para guardar inventarios, al principio habia hecho con mysql y todo bien pase la base de datos sqlite hice todas las modificaciones pero al momento de guardar se queda se queda tildado, es importante mencionar que la tabla donde se guardan tiene 7 columnas pero esta compilado para que el sistema agregue un id automaticamente y yo solo inserte 6 campos.

esxiste alguna manera para que pueda guardar de esta manera con este tipo de codigo?

```js
public int Guardar(String idinventario, String nombre, String tipo, String estatus, String ubicacion, String asignacion) throws SQLException {


  int resultado = 0;
  Connection con = null;

  String SSQL = "INSERT INTO inventario (idinventario, nombre, tipo, estatus, ubicacion, asignacion) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";



  try {

    con = metodospool.dataSource.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement psql = con.prepareStatement(SSQL);
    psql.setString(1, idinventario);
    psql.setString(2, nombre);
    psql.setString(3, tipo);
    psql.setString(4, estatus);
    psql.setString(5, ubicacion);
    psql.setString(6, asignacion);





    resultado = psql.executeUpdate();

    psql.close();


  } catch (SQLException e) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar almacenar la informacion\n" +
      e, "Error en la Operacion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);



  } finally {

    try {

      if (con != null) {

        con.close();
      }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerrar la conexion\n" +
        ex, "Error en la Operacion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
  }


  return resultado;





}

public int id_incrementar() {
  int id = 1;
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  pool metodospool = new pool();

  try {

    ps = metodospool.dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement("select max(idsistema) from inventario");
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {

      id = rs.getInt(1) + 1;


    }





  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error)" + e.getMessage());
  } finally {

    try {
      ps.close();
      rs.close();




    } catch (SQLException es) {}
  }


  return id;



}
```

no se por que me da error pero al modificar o eliminar filas lo hace sin problemas, alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

no me sale ningun error al darle al boton de guardar solo se queda pasamado pero lo he dejado varios minutos y no hace absolutamente nada debo terminar la app desde el administrador de tareas.

```js
public void Modificar(String idinventario, String nombre, String tipo, String estatus, String ubicacion, String asignacion, String idempleado) {

  int confirmar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea modificar los datos actuales?");


  if (confirmar == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

    Connection conexion = null;


    try {

      conexion = metodospool.dataSource.getConnection();

      String Ssql = "update inventario set idinventario=?, nombre=?, tipo=?, estatus=?, ubicacion=?, asignacion=? WHERE idsistema=? ";




      PreparedStatement prest = conexion.prepareStatement(Ssql);



      prest.setString(1, idinventario);
      prest.setString(2, nombre);
      prest.setString(3, tipo);
      prest.setString(4, estatus);
      prest.setString(5, ubicacion);
      prest.setString(6, asignacion);
      prest.setString(7, idempleado);


      if (prest.executeUpdate() > 0) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los datos han sido modificados con exito", "Operacion Exitosa", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);



      } else {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido realizar la operacion\n" +
          "Intentelo nuevamente", "Fallo la operacion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


      }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {


      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido realizar la operacion\n Intentelo nuevamente\"" +
        "Error" + ex, "Fallo la operacion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);




    } finally {

      if (conexion != null) {

        try {

          conexion.close();


        } catch (SQLException e) {

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido realizar la operacion" +
            "Error" + e, "Fallo la operacion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }



      }



    }




  }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no necesitas un método para incrementar un campo (`id_incrementar`), de hecho si tratas de incrementarlo y esta definido como llave primaría obtendras un error.

Si defines tu tabla con una llave primaria, en este caso el campo `idsistema`, no necesitas asignar programaticamente un valor que se incremente.

Por ejemplo, al crear tu  tabla defines una llave primaria:

```
CREATE TABLE inventario (idsistema INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, idinventario INTEGER, nombre TEXT, tipo TEXT, estatus TEXT, ubicacion TEXT, asignacion TEXT)
```

**Al insertar los valores, no necesitas indicar un valor para el campo `idsistema` ya que esta configurado como llave primaria (`PRIMARY KEY`)** y se asignará un valor automáticamente para este campo.

```
INSERT INTO inventario (idinventario, nombre, tipo, estatus, ubicacion, asignacion) VALUES (12321, "Hector", "tipo1","1", "Naucalpan", "asignado");
INSERT INTO inventario (idinventario, nombre, tipo, estatus, ubicacion, asignacion) VALUES (57712, "Mihai", "tipo2","0", "G.A.Madero", "no asignado");
INSERT INTO inventario (idinventario, nombre, tipo, estatus, ubicacion, asignacion) VALUES (67634, "Elena", "tipo3","2", "Iasi", "asignado");
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: excelente me funciono perfectocon ayuda de tus indicaciones